# InterceptingAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory Use

Tags: spring, spring-web

I was trying to understand the use of `InterceptingAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory`. When run test with MockRestServiceServer I saw requestFactory is decorated with this ResquestFactory. Is there any other use of this requestFactory? Basically I want to know the idea behind `InterceptingAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory`. As I couldn't find any examples to use it. 
Below code doesn't work.

```
    AsyncClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory(
            httpAsyncClient);
    List<AsyncClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<>(1);
    interceptors.add(asyncRestReqResInterceptor());
    AsyncClientHttpRequestFactory interceptorFactory = new InterceptingAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory(
            clientHttpRequestFactory, interceptors);
    AsyncRestTemplate asyncRestTemplate = new AsyncRestTemplate(interceptorFactory);
```

Please let me know the correct implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The general idea behind request factory is that you can customize how HttpAccessor implementations, like RestTemplate, makes requests. If you don't specify anything you get non-pooled `HttpURLConnection`, but spring offers factories for Appache HttpClient and other 3rd part libraries.

`InterceptingAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory` is a decorator, which allows you to plug-in Interceptors that modify the request befor it is sent. One such Interceptor is the `BasicAuthorizationInterceptor` which adds the Authorization header to every request. If you have stuff you need to do to every request you can create your own `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor`.

Comment: Thank @Klaus. I understood this part. but still when I try to use it as shown in my updated question, it doesn't work. Also we can add the interceptor from `setInterceptors` method of asyncRestTemplate.